# geometry nodes, how to make all faces laid out flat in XY. same-size?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, faces, edges

how can I make all faces laid out **flat in XY**. same-size?
**i need it for 2D printing.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify. Do you mean you want all faces laid out flat in XY. same-size? (That's not generally the same as UV mapping, so you may need to fix your terminology)

Comment: @RobinBetts sorry for my bad english, yes exactly, i want all faces laid out flat in XY.(same size)

Comment: No need for an apology :) . We'll try to help with English as much as we can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UV Editor, in the menu UV there's an option "Average Islands Scale". In geonodes you can achieve it like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice solution, thank you